# Printf two var's into a file

Tags: linux, bash, printf, snmp

I have a list of IP's I want to snmpget into a file. I'm having issues writing output to the file.

```
 OID=1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1
 cat printers.csv | while read IP ; do
        OUT=$(snmpget -v1 -c public $IP $OID)
        printf '%s, %s\n' $IP $OUT >> printerNames.csv
 done
```

I'm new to the printf command. I'm guessing that's where it's messing up bc output is being written just incorrectly. Also, when there is no response it echos to console and I'd like it written to the output file. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
OID=1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1
while read IP ; do
    OUT=$(snmpget -v1 -c public "$IP" "$OID") && printf '%s, %s\n' "$IP" "$OUT"
done < printers.csv 2>&1 > printerNames.csv
```

It's a good idea to always quote parameter expansions unless you have a good reason not to. The redirections are applied to the `while` loop. `read` will read a line at a time from the input file (no `cat` needed); anything written to standard error is instead copied to standard output, and the standard output (errors included) is redirected to the output file. The `printf` is only executed if the `snmpget` command succeeds (I'm assuming it has a non-zero exit status if the lookup fails; that may not be the case).

---

It sounds like `printers.csv` has DOS line endings (`\r\n`). The carriage return is included as the last character of each line. When you print `$IP`, it prints the address, then the carriage return, which moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line. This causes the remainder of the line (`, $OUT`) to overwrite the address. To remove the carriage return, run the input file through `dos2unix`, or use some other method to turn the DOS line endings into UNIX line endings (`\n` alone).

Comment: `$OUT` is now writing properly but `$IP` isn't being written and stderr isn't being redirected? output looks like `, iso.3.6... = STRING: "HP LaserJet P3005"` which is the correct output.

Comment: `2>&1` must be placed **after** `>printerNames.csv` in order to be redirected to the same file, otherwise it will be redirected to the *old* stdin.

Comment: Sir Athos that corrected the error redirect but for some reason `$IP` is not being written out. Is it possible to `printf` 2 variables?

Comment: Absolutely. What does a simple loop like `while read IP; do printf '%s\n' "$IP"; done < printers.csv` do?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like `printers.csv` has DOS line endings. Run it through `dos2unix`.